# What does UnityARAlignment mean in Unity ARKit Plugins?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit

[UnityARAlignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwCOI.png)

```
public enum UnityARAlignment
{
    UnityARAlignmentGravity,
    UnityARAlignmentGravityAndHeading,
    UnityARAlignmentCamera
}
```

As picture show, there are three options in Start Alignment. I want to know that what is the use of each option? What is their performance? I can't find the relevant information online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not documented yet but are ported based on [`ARConfiguration.WorldAlignment`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionconfiguration/worldalignment) enum in ARKit. The `UnityARAlignmentGravity`, `UnityARAlignmentGravityAndHeading` and `UnityARAlignmentCamera` enum values are mapped to Apple's ARKit [`gravity`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionconfiguration/worldalignment/gravity), [`gravityAndHeading`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionconfiguration/worldalignment/gravityandheading) and [`camera`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionconfiguration/worldalignment/camera) respectively.

From the Apple doc, below are short definition for them. Click on each one to read more about them. This mostly has nothing to do with performance but instead helps configure the orientation of the camera or compass.

- [`UnityARAlignment`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionconfiguration/worldalignment) enum is equivalent to
  [`ARConfiguration.WorldAlignment`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionconfiguration/worldalignment) - Options for how ARKit
  constructs a scene coordinate system based on real-world device
  motion.
- [`UnityARAlignmentGravity`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionconfiguration/worldalignment/gravity) - The coordinate system's y-axis is
  parallel to gravity, and its origin is the initial position of the
  device.
- [`UnityARAlignmentGravityAndHeading`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionconfiguration/worldalignment/gravityandheading) - The coordinate system's y-axis
  is parallel to gravity, its x- and z-axes are oriented to compass
  heading, and its origin is the initial position of the device.
- [`UnityARAlignmentCamera`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionconfiguration/worldalignment/camera) - The scene coordinate system is locked to
  match the orientation of the camera.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry for some delays in modifying my comments. I have accepted your answer. In addition, I already understand the meaning of the three options. However, in practice, when I choose *Gravity And Heading*, the screen will get stuck when the application is running. And when theapplication is opened for the first time, it only prompts whether to provide the camera used permission and does not prompt whether to provide the location tracking permission. Although I have added key in Info.plist. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Said in the official documentation note: "Your app's Info.plist must include user-facing text for the NSLocationUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key so that the user can grant your app permission for location tracking.". So I added the options _Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description and Privacy - Location Usage Description_ in Info.plist. However, when the app starts, he only prompts me to provide the camera permission but does not provide permission to obtain the location information. Then my application screen will get stuck, but in fact it is still running.