# How to point a model in ARkit to north pole in real world?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, orientation

Hi I am trying to a model always in north direction.How to get the north pole direction on real world .

```
public class PointNoeth : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
//void Start () 
IEnumerator Start()
{
    // First, check if user has location service enabled
    if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
        yield break;

    // Start service before querying location
    Input.location.Start();

    // Wait until service initializes
    int maxWait = 20;
    while (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        maxWait--;
    }

    // Service didn't initialize in 20 seconds
    if (maxWait < 1)
    {
        print("Timed out");
        yield break;
    }

    // Connection has failed
    if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed)
    {
        print("Unable to determine device location");
        yield break;
    }
    else
    {
        // Access granted and location value could be retrieved
        print("Location: " + Input.location.lastData.latitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.longitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.altitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy + " " + Input.location.lastData.timestamp);
    }

    // Stop service if there is no need to query location updates continuously
    Input.location.Stop();

    Input.compass.enabled = true;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, -Input.compass.trueHeading, 0);

    /
}
}
```

In the Update function I have set the rotation.I have kept arrow mark as my model .Initially I have kept it pointing in z direction but when I hit play it changes to -x axis.Same happens when i checked in my device.When I checked where the real world north pole using tools in my phone it is in the opposite direction.So how to point my model in north pole [image: Initial position].

[image: After Playing]

Comment: Well, in the editor, your object is rotated to `(90, 0, -90)` and your code tells it to rotate to `(0, $heading, 0)`...

Answer (score 0):

You can change the world alignment to be based on the compass heading, then when placing your object you can rotate it based on [AR Kit World Alignment](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionconfiguration/worldalignment/gravityandheading)

To do this you need to configure it using ARKitSessionConfiguration with the parameter UnityARAlignment.UnityARAlignmentGravityAndHeading
More info about the enums can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716817/what-does-unityaralignment-mean-in-unity-arkit-plugins)

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this with `Input.compass.magneticHeading`.
You can check the official documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Compass-magneticHeading.html) for more details.

After detecting the plane and placing the ar object I rotate it like this

```
arObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, -Input.compass.magneticHeading, 0f);
```

That will rotate the object to face north.
Now if I want to face it south, I would do something like

```
private float directionOffset = 180f;// 0f - north, 45f - northeast, 90f - east, 135f - southeast etc.
arObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, -Input.compass.magneticHeading + directionOffset, 0f);
```

Hope it helps.